# How to use appdelegate variable in view

Tags: iphone

i declared a variable `NSString productname` in appdelegate and assigned value `appdelegate.productname = name` from a view.Then i tried to get this value from another `view.lbl.text=appdelegate.productname`. Is this is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you can declare variables in appdelegate.h file, these variables are global you dont need to make appdelegate object to calling them.

like this -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

// these are your variable, both are global. 
int anyNumber; 
NSString *productname;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *naviCon;

@end
```

Now you can use these variables at any where you want to use.

just import the appdelegate.h and use it freely.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

this is your first view from where you are assigning the value to appdelegate string.

```
productname = name; //you can assign it directly, no need to make any object of appdelegate.
```

now you can use it any where. but remember little thing you have to import

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

in your viewcontroller.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with this code:

```
UIApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *productName = appDelegate.productname;
```

Comment: it is showing error use of undeclared identifier uiapplicationdelegate

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate here i mentioned the name of the app delegate class of your project. #import the appdelegate class of your project into your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString * str = appDelegate.yourstr;
```