# pass parameters from push notification to viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, web, push

I have an ios app which loads a webpage to show data. I use push notifications for receiving news and I want that depending of which push is received, goes to one page or other (sections inside the same page).

In the text received in push notification, I add a word before the text, something like:

```
page1 - text
page2 - text2
page3 - text3
...
```

In android I take the first word and add to the webpage url: www.page.com/ + pageAdded

In iOs I think I haveto add this code to didFinishLaunchWithOptions function. But I don't know where I should add the new code for passing the arguments. I add my function so you can tell me where to put it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"CityInfoPush" accessGroup:nil];
    udid = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    //if udid is empty , that means we need to generate one and save it on KeyChain
    if([udid length] == 0){
        NSLog(@"No CFUUID found. Creating one...");
        //creating CFUUID
        CFUUIDRef cfuuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        NSString *cfuuidString = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfuuid));
        NSLog(@"Device CFUUID created is : %@" , cfuuidString);
        //saving CFUUID on KeyChain
        [keychainItem setObject: cfuuidString forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

        //retrieving CFUUID from KeyChain and passing it to udid String.
        udid = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];        
    }

    //For reseting the keyChain (testing)
    //[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];

    NSLog(@"Password Saved in KeyChain is: %@" , udid);


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

I add the message to the payload for sending it to the apple server like this:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
```

I am trying to get the alert text (message) in ios like this, but always fails and crash the app:

```
NSString *text=[[lastNotif valueForKeyPath:@"aps"][0] objectForKey:@"alert"];
```

Comment: What do you need to know? My question is how to pass data to view controller when I receive a push. Also I need to know where I have to read the text received in the push notification

Comment: already `didRecieveRemoteNotification` is in appDel. You can access them throughout project by creating appDel reference as `AppDelegate *ap=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

Comment: Do I have to do this in view controller? How do I read text after that?

Comment: refere this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736812/how-to-use-appdelegate-variable-in-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can check if you app has been launched with a puch notification in your `application:
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function with :

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey])
```

What I do is save this notification in the userDefaults :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] forKey:@"notificationReceived"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then in the viewDidLoad where you want to catch your push notification, check if you have one in memory :

```
NSDictionary *lastNotif = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notificationReceived"];
if (lastNotif != nil)
{
    //handle what you want to do with your notification

    //now don't forget to clean userDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"notificationReceived"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: don't forget to have a look at this very useful guidelines about how send push notification https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: In lastNotif, do I access to data like this: lastNotif[text]?

Comment: I am trying to use your code adding a NSLog but it is never fired. I try to close the app, receive the push and open it from push notif but nothing happends.

Comment: I think it is fired but I can't use it due to it charsh my app. It never read the message using a for or something to run the nsdictionary

Comment: I've just corrected a mistake when getting my object `lastNotif` (mistake in the key @"notificationReceived"). This object is a dictionary, build with the JSON object you send for  notification (see the link in my first comment). So each value of this dictionary can be retrieve with `objectForKey:`

Comment: I solved it, I was reading the value in the wrong way I didn't need to use [0]. Thanks man, your code works like a charm.